# Elegant Efficient way of inserting into a lot of tables MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am making a survey and currently the database has 19 tables and roughly 100 columns. All of them will be inserted to as they are required fields. I am looking for an Elegant and Efficient way of inserting into that many tables and columns. So far what I have come up with is to create a multidimensional array that contains the first key as the table name and the second key as the column name with the field. Something like below:

```
    $tableArray =  array( 
        'ownerTable' => array(
            'firstNameRow' => $firstName,
            'lastNameRow' => $lastName
        ),
        'dealerTable' => array(
            'dealerNameRow' => $dealerName,
            'dealerCityRow' => $dealerCity
            )
        );

foreach($tableArray as $row => $key) {
    foreach($tableArray[$row] as $row1) {
        $sql = "(INSERT INTO $tableArray[$key] ($tableArray[$row]) VALUES ($row1)"; 
    }   
}
```

I didn't test this code but I am thinking something along those lines would work. I think one problem I see with this is a separate `INSERT` for each column instead of one `INSERT` for each table. I can always work on writing the code to just load all the values from the array at once to solve this problem but before I start getting to carried away I want to make sure I am not making a big mistake and waste time if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: 19 tables and 100 columns seems a bit inefficient for a survey.

Comment: I would post as an answer but I'm not definite on this. Maybe break it up like `$sql = "insert into";` => your 2 foreach functions then `$sql .= $tableArray[$key] ." ( ".$tableArray[$row] .") VALUES ( ".$row1 ." )";` then run `mysql_query($sql);` I hope that makes sense I'm on my phone but your table names/values should be in the loops and then outside your loops run your query. then it should only be really one insert if my logic is right

Comment: @helion3 by inefficient what do you mean? To few tables for the amount of columns or to many columns for the number of tables? I could honestly probably split up the columns into more tables but figured since most of the bloat is from simple yes or no answers it probably wouldn't matter since they all relate to each other.

Comment: I just mean in general - 19 tables sounds excessive, and 100 columns does as well. I don't know the details of the system of course but I've done a dozen private and government large-scale survey sites and never needed that many tables/columns.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the structure of your database on your surveys. This is my first survey and it has 34 questions but a large array of answers. Such as: `What type of dealer are you?` which I am listing 7 check boxes with an other text field. I put this question inside of its own table with separate columns for each check box that can be either a `1` or `0` I realize I could have concatenated the values separated by a semicolon and inserted them into one row but I figured adding separate columns would be easier for readability. This pattern repeats throughout the survey questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tableArray =  array( 
        'ownerTable' => array(
            'firstNameRow' => $firstName,
            'lastNameRow' => $lastName
        ),
        'dealerTable' => array(
            'dealerNameRow' => $dealerName,
            'dealerCityRow' => $dealerCity
            )
        );

//it's for bulj query execution in single statment;
$i=1;
$sql="";
foreach($tableArray as $row => $key) {
    foreach($tableArray[$row] as $row1) {
        //here you can update i value as per row for execution
        if($i<=25)
        {
         $sql = $sql  + "(INSERT INTO $tableArray[$key] ($tableArray[$row]) VALUES ($row1);"; 
        }
        else
        {
            //execute sql statement here;
            $i=0;
            $sql="";
        }
    }   
}
```